# How insert text after title tag in all htmls files in project?

Tags: eclipse

I have to add text for example `<meta tag...>` in my project in all files "**.html*" after "*`<title>title page</title>*` text.
For Example:

```
.....blablalbalblala
        <title>title page</title>
         **<meta... tag/>**    //inserted text 
    .....
```

I know how to find *.html files with text ... but how to add text after this tag?

Answer (score 1):

- Search for all occurrences of `</title>`
- In the Search view, remove all matches that you don't want to replace
- Invoke the context menu, choose `Replace All...`
- Replace your matches with `</title><meta... tag/>`

If you want the meta tag to be placed on a new line, you can search with the checkbox for `Regular expression` enabled. Then you can replace with `</title>\n  <meta... tag/>`

You can then also reference matches from your search:

- searching for `<tile>([^<]+)</title>`
- and replacing with `\0\n<meta \1/>`
- will e.g. change `<title>abcd</title` into

  <title>abcd</title>
  <meta abcd/>

Answer (score 1):

Refer images. Select your **project** in package explorer, I selected package. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

[image]

Note down the number of **search hits** after searching. In below picture it is present below the view toolbar. Here it is 3.

[image]

**Replace hits**(in below picture it is above the **Replace** **Replace** text box i.e 3) must match the **search hit** shown in above picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you'are using Linux, you can open a terminal, going in your project dir and do:

```
A="<meta tag...>"
B="</title>"
awk -v "pattern=$A" '{print} /^$B/ && !x {print A; x=1}' filename > tmp
cat tmp > filename
rm tmp
```

if you want to apply to all your file, make a script, say "addMeta":

```
#!/bin/bash

cd $1
A="<meta tag...>"
B="</title>"
for file in $(find -name "*.html"); do
    awk -v "pattern=$A" '{print} /^$B/ && !x {print A; x=1}' ${file} > tmp
    cat tmp > ${file}
    rm tmp
done
```

And then you can:

```
chmod +x addMeta
./addMeta ~/workspace/Project
```

Script is to prefer to ctrl+F and Replace **IF** you have to do this modify to many files.